# Eliminating effectively-redundant entries with Inner Join

Tags: mysql, mariadb

The problem that we are trying to solve can be explained with the following illustrative example.

We have the following two tables:

```
CREATE table moniker_tbl
(
  id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name VARCHAR(20),
  nickname VARCHAR(20),

  PRIMARY KEY(id)
);


CREATE table student_tbl
(
  id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name VARCHAR(20),
  stipend INT,

  PRIMARY KEY(id)
);
```

These tables are populated as follows:

```
INSERT INTO moniker_tbl(name, nickname) VALUES ('John Doe', 'Jonny'),
('John Doe', 'The Doe Man'), ('Richard Stevens', 'Rickie'),
('William Smith', 'Billy'), ('William Smith', 'Smithie');

INSERT INTO student_tbl(name, stipend) VALUES ('John Doe', '5000'),
('Richard Stevens', '7000'), ('William Smith', '6000');
```

We perform the following INNER JOIN operation:

```
SELECT t1.nickname, t2.stipend
FROM moniker_tbl AS t1
INNER JOIN student_tbl AS t2
ON t1.name = t2.name;
```

We get the following results:

```
+-------------+---------+
| nickname    | stipend |
+-------------+---------+
| Jonny       |    5000 |
| The Doe Man |    5000 |
| Rickie      |    7000 |
| Billy       |    6000 |
| Smithie     |    6000 |
+-------------+---------+
```

We would like the results to show only one entry per nickname e.g.

```
+-------------+---------+
| nickname    | stipend |
+-------------+---------+
| Jonny       |    5000 |
| Rickie      |    7000 |
| Billy       |    6000 |
+-------------+---------+
```

Comment: What criteria do you use to exclude the other nicknames?

Comment: @mustaccio In our application it does not matter what nickname we choose, so long as we account for each name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
SELECT ANY_VALUE(t1.nickname) nickname, t2.stipend
FROM moniker_tbl AS t1
INNER JOIN student_tbl AS t2 ON t1.name = t2.name
GROUP BY t2.name, t2.stipend;
```

Comment: If the version you are running does not have `ANY_VALUE`, you can use `MIN` (or `MAX`) instead.

Answer (score 0):

## TL;DR

Deterministic functions are better than non-deterministic ones in this use case. Either the deterministic MIN()/MAX() functions can be used to select the required data (similarly performant<sup>1</sup> or window functions (more powerful and flexible) - in this case, the ROW_NUMBER() function.

<sup>(1) Edit: using the MySQL [profiling functionality](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d84bc5b973279ca7d94dd82279f060de), I found that the speeds of the MIN() queries compared to the ANY_VALUE() queries were similar and depended much more on which query was run first (caching...) than on the function!</sup>

---

## Introduction:

Firstly, I would advise against using the `ANY_VALUE()` function for the reasons outlined [here](https://riptutorial.com/mysql/example/26731/any-value--) - the post author amusingly renames it the `SURPRISE_ME()` function. From the page:

> The server doesn't choose a random value, it's worse than that. It
> returns the same value every time you run the query, until it doesn't.
> It can change, or not, when a table grows or shrinks, or when the
> server has more or less RAM, or when the server version changes, or
> when Mars is in retrograde (whatever that means), or for no reason at
> all.

Basically, it's a non-deterministic SQL function (like [RAND()](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_rand.asp) for example) and non-determinism is not an ideal characteristic of a database query! This means that for the same input data you are not guaranteed to receive the same output - your returned dataset may vary as outlined above - apart from the bit about Mars... maybe...!

You would be far better off using either the MIN() or MAX() functions (as outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37089653/470530)). These **are** deterministic and have been around a long time - and appear to be more performant - see the fiddles.

Also, and perhas the best option, you can use the [window function](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-window-functions/) [`ROW_NUMBER()`](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-window-functions/mysql-row_number-function/) which **is** deterministic and very flexible and powerful.

Note that I have used MySQL version 8.0.23 where CHECK constraints are honoured (since 8.0.16 - **only** ~ 30 after they'd made it into the SQL standard!) and window functions also work.

Window functions work back to MariaDB 10.3 - not sure about CHECKs - you'll have to use TRIGGERs otherwise. I'm a big believer (as you'll see below) in using DDL to enforce rules to the greatest possible extent - your server is your last bastion for the defence of the integrity of your data - if you let rubbish in, you'll only get [rubbish out](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_in,_garbage_out)!

## First part - using your schema ([fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=49bef21241f9c70dc00dd7e1bf35c341)):

Because you are joining on the student.name field, this should be UNIQUE in the student table. So, the the student table should now look like this:

```
CREATE table student
(
  id INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name VARCHAR(20)    NOT NULL,
  stipend INTEGER     NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  
  CONSTRAINT student_pk_id   PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT student_name_uq UNIQUE (name),
  
  CONSTRAINT student_name_length_5_ck     CHECK (LENGTH(name) >= 5),
  CONSTRAINT student_name_stipend_gt_0_ck CHECK (stipend >= 0)
);
```

The UNIQUE constraint on student.name [creates an INDEX](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-unique-constraint/#:%7E:text=MySQL%20UNIQUE%20constraints%20and%20indexes,index%20to%20enforce%20the%20rule.) on student.name - so it's unnecessary to create one manually (from [here](http://When%20you%20define%20a%20unique%20constraint,%20MySQL%20creates%20a%20corresponding%20UNIQUE%20index%20and%20uses%20this%20index%20to%20enforce%20the%20rule.):

> When you define a unique constraint, MySQL creates a corresponding
> UNIQUE index and uses this index to enforce the rule.

I've also added some reasonable `NOT NULL` and `CHECK` constraints - it makes no sense to have a NULL name and its `LENGTH()` should be greater than (or at least equalt to) 5, a negative stipend makes no sense and a DEFAULT of 0 makes sense in the absence of information to the contrary.

For versions of MySQL <= 8.0.16, the CHECK constraints will be parsed but not enforced - not even a warning... another reason to look at alternative F/LOSS databases...

So, now we turn our attention to the `moniker` table which I've modified as follows:

```
CREATE table moniker
(
  id INTEGER UNSIGNED  NOT NULL,
  name VARCHAR(20)     NOT NULL,
  nickname VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,

  CONSTRAINT moniker_pk_id PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT moniker_student_name_fk FOREIGN KEY (name) REFERENCES student (name),
  CONSTRAINT moniker_name_nickname_uq UNIQUE (name, nickname),
  
  CONSTRAINT monikder_nname_len_gteq_2_ck CHECK (LENGTH(nickname) >= 2)
);
```

Now moniker.name is a FOREIGN KEY into the student.name field. There's a UNIQUE constraint on (name, nickname) - a given name can't have the same nickname twice.

From here:

> MySQL requires that foreign key columns be indexed; if you create a
> table with a foreign key constraint but no index on a given column, an
> index is created.

So, no requirement to create one explicitly.

A UNIQUE constraint on nickname might be tricky since, to take the example of my own country, there are many people called "Fitzgerald", "Fitzsimons" & "Fitzharris" &c... all of whom might be nicknamed "Fitzie" or "Fitzer".

So, now you have two (deterministic) choices for your query:

The relatively simple MIN() or MAX() as follows (only MIN() shown):

```
SELECT MIN(t1.nickname) AS n_name, t2.stipend
FROM moniker AS t1
JOIN student AS t2
  ON t1.name = t2.name
GROUP BY t2.name, t2.stipend
ORDER BY t2.stipend;
```

Result:

```
n_name  stipend
Jonny   5000
Billy   6000
Rickie  7000
```

So, that's fine. Now, we look at the ROW_NUMBER() window function which is used as follows:

```
SELECT m.nname, s.stipend
FROM 
student s
JOIN
(
  SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY name, nickname) AS rn,
    name, nickname AS nname
  FROM moniker
) AS m
  ON s.name = m.name
WHERE m.rn = 1
ORDER BY s.stipend;
```

Result:

```
nname   stipend
Jonny   5000
Billy   6000
Rickie  7000
```

Which is the same as for the MIN() function because in my ORDER BY clause, I have (name, nickname) which will pick the first nickname alphabetically (i.e. the MIN()) for a given student name.

I cannot emphasise enough the power of window functions and it would be well worth your while getting to know and understand them - they will repay any effort you make ten times over very quickly!

## Second part - modified schema ([fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=fab82a9d5e0ca866684f337a51c245b2)):

What **I** would do here is to use the student.id field to join the student and moniker tables - and I'd make the PK of the moniker table a combination of student_id and nname - so that no student can have the same nickname twice.

The whole question appears to be predicated on the assumption that no nickname can occur twice - as I mention above, this is rather unlikely unless you enforce a UNIQUE constraint on moniker.nickname - if you don't do this, then the results could potentially become meaningless as two students with the same nickname could potentially have the same stipend leading to a resultset with two identical records - a bag rather than a set and this is not good if further processing goes on down the line... So, what you really have to do is keep the student.student_id associated with the nickname and the stipend in the final result - as follows:

```
CREATE table moniker
(
  student_id MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  nickname VARCHAR(20),

  CONSTRAINT moniker_sid_nname_pk PRIMARY KEY(student_id, nickname),
  CONSTRAINT moniker_student_id_fk
    FOREIGN KEY (student_id) REFERENCES student (id),
  
  CONSTRAINT moniker_nname_len_gteq_2_ck CHECK (LENGTH(nickname) >= 2)

);
```

From [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/integer-types.html), MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED should be enough to keep you going (~ 16M)- with less space requirements and faster joins on two indexed MEDIUMINT fields. We have to adjust the student.id datatype accordingly - see the [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=fab82a9d5e0ca866684f337a51c245b2).

I added a record to the student table and to the moniker table to show my point - note students 2 & 4 having the same nickname, "Rickie"!:

```
INSERT INTO student
VALUES (1, 'John Doe', 5000),      (2, 'Richard Stevens', 7000), 
       (3, 'William Smith', 6000), (4, 'Rich Vaughan', 7000);
```

and

```
INSERT INTO moniker
VALUES (1, 'Jonny'),
(1, 'The Doe Man'), (2, 'Rickie'),
(3, 'Billy'), (3, 'Smithie'), (4, 'Rickie');
```

and my ROW_NUMBER() query becomes:

```
SELECT s.id, m.nname, s.stipend
FROM 
student s
JOIN
(
  SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY student_id 
                         ORDER BY student_id, nickname) AS rn,
    student_id, nickname AS nname
  FROM moniker
) AS m
  ON s.id = m.student_id
WHERE m.rn = 1
ORDER BY s.stipend;
```

Result:

```
id    nname   stipend
 1    Jonny      5000
 3    Billy      6000
 2   Rickie      7000
 4   Rickie      7000
```

Notice that we can now distinguish between Rickie - student_id 2 and Rickie - student_id 4.

I have used MySQL version 8.0.23 which enforces CHECK constraints and also has the useful EXPLAIN ANALYZE functionality - it appears that MIN() is actually more performant than ANY_VALUE(), so quite why anyone would choose the latter is beyond me! As for the window function, its performance is not so great, but these functions are much more powerful and flexible than the simple MIN()/MAX() ones and may be worth condsidering should your requirements evolve - in any case, they're all better than ANY_VALUE() (IMHO...).